# Simple socket library need some check

Tags: c, sockets

First I am sorry for posting code as ugly style, I didn't know the right tag for styling, now back to my code as it posted here: [Simple socket library need some check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550400/c-languagesimple-socket-library-need-some-check)
My problem now with the server I create based in the previous library, it return -1 when I call socket_open, witch is look its fail to create socket, I tried to debug it but I didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: I don't know whether you'll be allowed to post questions again, but generally it's better to edit existing questions rather than create a question mentioning a past question.

Comment: @Andrew I think I am now allowed to ask, I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in the socket call the protocol and type are backwards. You want to do this:

```
int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

But the way you set protocol and type in the main program make the call be:

```
int s = socket(AF_INET, 0, SOCK_STREAM);
```

Where you are wrong:

1: In stest.c you set this:

```
socket->domain = AF_INET;
socket->type = SOCK_STREAM;
socket->protocol = 0;
```

This should be:

```
socket->domain = AF_INET;
socket->protocol = SOCK_STREAM
socket->type = 0;
```

2: OpenSocket.c

When you check the return code from socket you are checking for fd being zero. Zero does not indicate failure; -1 means it failed. socket_connect has the same problem.

3: You're also passing structures by value instead of by reference. This potentially may not work the way you want if you are assuming that values updated in the structures in the socket library are going to be seen by the calling function.

4: There is a memory leak in socket_recv_len and a potential memory leak in socket_recv. The buffer you malloc doesn't get freed but is not returned to the caller to let them free it.

5: For the send and recv system calls a return code of zero means the connection was closed nicely. A return code of -1 means an error (connection aborted, etc.).

Comment: Now it can create socket but it can not listen, I think the problem in this line: tsock->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
Byway how I can start new line in this tiny editor.

Comment: You are calling bind with the wrong parameters, because sock_i is a pointer to sockaddr_in and then you are passing the address of a sock_i then you are passing sockaddr_in ** instead of sockaddr_in * (the cast does not resolve this problem), and finally you are passing the size of sock_i (4 bytes) instead of size of sockaddr_in (16 bytes).

Comment: I made some change and now it can listening in given port:
<code>
stat = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)tsock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
</code>
Now I have problem in the connect function, it failes after a period of time.
Another question how to get new line, and why my code is doesn't styled like other's.